# What the format requirement or language requirement of the corpus using by LDA-Ruby?

Tags: ruby, nlp, lda

I am using LDA-ruby to perform topic modelling of Chinese tweets content. However, when use txt file as my own TextCorpus the result is quite strange. First time, the result topics were all English letters which occurred in the content; then I stripped out all letters of the input files for the corpus, and the result still make no sense. So does the lda-ruby only work with English corpus or any special requirements needed for building my own corpus? 
(btw. new to ruby/nlp)

Thanks in advance if any solution of how to build corpus (format/language).

Comment: I added the [tag:nlp] and [tag:lda] tags. I hope that helps. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: There's a sample corpus here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/lda-c/ (see "2246 documents from the Associated Press") maybe you could learn something from its format? I don't know :)